# I get an error whenever i try to run "npm install" on visual studio code

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

whenever I run npm install I get this error
I am on node version 18.9.1 and I have tried every single solution please help

```
'''npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive\Desktop\cw/package.json
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive\Desktop\cw\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent'''
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a `package.json`? What do you expect `npm install` to do without `package.json`?

Comment: _"I have tried every single solution"_ Is a bit vague! If you've tried _everything_, there's likely nothing we could suggest that you haven't already tried. Please be specific and tell us what you have done to try and resolve this. May be there _is_ something you've missed.

Comment: Are you running npm install on the correct folder? I.e. the one with the package.json file in?

Answer (score -3):

`npm install --force` did the trick. I also had to add `"type": "module"`,
and also I was using got so instead of `require()` I used `import`

Comment: Why would you call `npm install --force` without `package.json`? What are you trying to achieve? If you want to initialize a Node.js package, you can run `npm init` or `npm init -y`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).